# Does "in any conscious or dishonest way" refer to the former statement?

Tags: meaning, time-reference

Does "in any conscious or dishonest way" refer to the former statement?
i mean. refer to "i have observed many.."

In speaking of Miss Kate Fox,
Professor Crookes says: "I have observed many circumstances which
appear to show that the will and intelligence of the medium have much
to do with the phenomena." He adds that this is not **in any conscious or
dishonest way**, and continues, "I have observed some circumstances
which seem conclusively to point to the agency of an outside
intelligence not belonging to any human being in the room."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He, Crooke, seems to be saying that when observing Kate Fox, her will and intelligence may be affecting the phenomena (whatever that is?) but he does not consider her influence to be happening consciously or by dishonestly.

Comment: When do we get to read about the big dog?

Comment: i searched about the big dog. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/big-dog. but i still cannot  understand. it is because of our different cultures.

Comment: Okay, I'll explain my joke.  You are citing passages from a very obscure book by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. Hardly anyone knows about it. I was playing with the stackexchange audience by implying that I'm a bit dumb in thinking these passages were from another, very famous, book by the same author.  Its one that everyone has heard of called 'The Hound of the Baskervilles' and tells the story of a monstrous dog terrorizing the inhabitants of Dartmoore.

Comment: @ Bruce Murray what is your opinion about this book? when you see that it is not a story but it is a history. i read but i don't know should i believe Doyle or not? this is my first encounter with Doyle. explain a little.

Comment: If you are interested in esotericism, particularly spiritualism, it's a decent read.  I am not (interested) myself.  The Victorian era prose is extremely difficult to navigate, even more so for you, I imagine.  I have to think quite hard about what is written in order to answer your questions.

Comment: thank you very much. yes. the context is a little ambiguous.

Comment: You can believe that Doyle is sincere in his history, and his investigation, of spiritualism. But you should remember that whatever "evidence" was obtained, none of it really stood up to scientific scrutiny, as the passage in your [recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250974/what-does-capricious-manner-here-mean-but-seldom-rarely) admits. IMO the entire matter is based on an understanding of psychology, and what people *want* to believe. Like cloud-gazing, our minds create what they expect to see. Perception and reality are quite different things.

Comment: @Weather Vane i agree that there were no scientific proof. but i do not agree with  the example of cloud-gazing. because it is not fair in my opinion.